# jqgrid data comes as undefined while grouping

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid.I am using following code as a simple example.Data comes out be correct without grouping but with grouping it is unable to capture data(placeid) not shown in the row.I understand that on grouping, rowObject does not have placeid but how do I go about resolving the issue.
jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/johnnash03/6jhqgxw8/5/

```
        var rows = [{
              "place": "Kerala",
              "placeid": "61",
              "code": "kc10",
        }]

        var cols =  ["place","code"];
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames: cols,
            colModel: [{
                name: 'place',
            }, {
                name: 'code',
                formatter: function( cellvalue, options, rowObject ) {
                    return rowObject['placeid']
                }
            }]
        });

        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,rows[i]);

        // Data comes correct on commenting following line.
        $("#grid").jqGrid( 'groupingGroupBy', 'place');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your demo is the usage of the property `placeid`, which isn't in any columns of the grid. You fills additionally the grid using `addRowData` method called in the loop. It's the slowest way to fill the grid, which I know. The most important in your case is that the internal `data` of the grid will be filled only with `place`, `code` and `id` properties. No `placeid` property will be saved locally. Thus one don't see it during the later groping the grid.

One can solves the problem by usage `additionalProperties` option, which specify the names of additional properties of input items, which needed be saved in the local `data`. Adding

```js
additionalProperties: ["placeid"]
```

option solves the issue. See the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/6jhqgxw8/8/

I'd strictly recommend you to modify the code to about the following:

```js
var rows = [{
      "place": "Kerala",
      "placeid": "61",
      "code": "kc10",
}];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: rows,
    colModel: [
        { name: "place" },
        { name: "code",
            formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
                return options.rowData.placeid;
            }
        }
    ],
    grouping: true, 
    groupingView : { 
        groupField : ["place"]
    },
    localReader: { id: "placeid" }
});
```

Where one can add optionally `additionalProperties: ["placeid"]` too. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/6jhqgxw8/9/.

The above code create, fills and group the data at once. It uses `localReader: { id: "placeid" }` additionally to inform that `placeid` property has the rowid information (the unique values used as the values of `id` property of the rows: `<tr>` elements) instead of default `id` property.